# Does Azure Data Factory support Active Directory Authentication in Linked Services? If yes then what should be the connection string?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-data-factory

We have a requirement where all the other authentication modes like windows and sql server authentication will be retired and we will have to use only AAD authentication in our Azure data factory pipelines. So I want to know is it possible to implement AAD authentication in Azure Data Factory linked services.

Answer (score 1):

The link service of Azure Data factor is used to connect to external resources.

Based on my understanding, it should depend on whether the external resources supported to AAD authentication. For example, the Azure SQL database support Azure AD authentication. However, based on the test, the Azure SQL database doesn't support to connect it using the **Active Directory Password** connection at present.

What's the specific external resource you want to support for Azure AD authentication?

And if you have any good idea or feedback about Azure, you can try to submit it from [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback).

Comment: Yes the external resource which is a Azure SQL Server supports only Active Directory Integrated Authentication. I am able to connect to this server from SSMS using Active Directory Integrated Authentication but  I need to know if it is possible to connect to the external resource from Azure Linked Services in ADF using AAD authentication.
For example
"connectionString": "Data Source=tcp:xxxxx.database.secure.windows.net;Initial Catalog=xxxxxx;Authentication=Active Directory Integrated;User ID=xxxxx".
Above is throwing an error "Specified connection string is not valid"

Comment: No, it doesn't support yet.  Other communities already rise the feedback [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/270578-data-factory/suggestions/16436656-aad-authentication-support-for-azure-sql-database), you can vote it if you also want this feature.

Answer (score 0):

The AAD support has been added recently to ADFv2, there are two scenarios supported:

- Service principal - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-sql-database#using-service-principal-authentication
- Using managed service identity - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-sql-database#using-managed-service-identity-authentication